# Azure cosmos db is faster without partition key

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm confusing about the partition key with cosmos db. I have a database/container with about 4000 small records. If I try a sql statement with my partition key filter, the RUs and the duration time is larger then without.

Does someone understand this?

in this sample my partition key of the container is /partitionKey

I tried this statement: 
SELECT * FROM  c where  c.partitionKey = 'userSettings' And c.deleted =false

Request Charge      50 RUs
Document load time  2.15 ms

and then this 
SELECT * FROM  c where  c.cosmosEntityName = 'userSettings' And c.deleted =false

Request Charge      5 RUs
Document load time  0.38 ms

I expect exactly the opposite results.

Here some screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `cosmosEntityName` isn't the partition key? This looks weird. Can you execute those queries in the portal and paste here pictures of the query metrics tab?

Comment: I just added screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is very specific to the topology of your collection (which Azure support can help with), but generally speaking there are two cases where the latter query on non-partition key property can be lower in RUs than the partition key property:

List item

- If the query on non-partition key property is incomplete, the RUs may appear lower, but you still need to read results from other partitions to ascertain there are no more results. You would have to click "More Results" in Data Explorer until it is grayed out
- For this specific query `where c.partitionKey = 'userSettings' And c.deleted =false`, you should compare RUs with and without a composite index on `/partitionKey/?` and `/deleted/?` (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-indexing-policy#composite-indexing-policy-examples). In some cases, you will get lower RUs with the composite index than with the default of `/*` which only indexes them individually, potentially close to ~5 RUs